# Runtime Error while running the VS2008 solution; Solution is building fine

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, runtime-error

I am getting the error dialog box:

> "Unable to start program "C:\Users\James\Desktop\MyAppSourceCode\Release\Myapp.exe".
>   C:\Users\James\Desktop\MyAppSourceCode\Release" is not a valid working directory. "

when I try to run (F5 or F10) the VS2008 solution (VC++).

It's compiling with no errors. I also tried cleaning entire soln & rebuilding it. 
But still getting this error.

In the solution directory there is a folder called Release too.

I don't understand why am I getting such an error. I strongly feel this is a VS issue because the same code is running fine in another system.

Can anyone kindly help me in getting rid of this runtime error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are those dots from you, or really part of the names?

Comment: And what's with those forward slashes?  Post *real* error messages, don't edit them.

Comment: Yes I have pasted the error message as it is. Have done the necessary modifications to the question body. PLaese have a look @ the error.

Comment: You've got a folder name, find out what is wrong with it.  Does it exist?  Does it contain an exe?  If it doesn't, where did the exe go?

Answer (score 1):

Set your working directory.

In the project tab, open debugging and set it to $(ProjectDir), if your code resides near compiled binaries. You can change the address to the other folder where the nmake places them.